# How to restart either process when it kills automatically

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, automation

i have 2 processes which needs to run simultaneously (process1 and process2-same names).

i wrote a script which will automatically restarts all the 2 processes if those 2 killed.
but i am stuck at the point where if either of the process (anyone) is killed ,then the particular process not restarting.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /Desktop/XYZ/

./process1 &

cd /Desktop/XYX/new/

./process1 &

while :
do

while pgrep process1 >/Desktop/XYZ/out.txt;

do

   sleep 5

done
    cd /Desktop/XYZ/

    ./process1 &

   cd /Desktop/XYX/new/

./process1 &

   sleep 10
done
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you currently check if the processes has been killed? The usual way is to start them in the background and record their pid (process id) in a file. Then you can regularly use this file to see if the pid is alive and have the correct name (since pids can be reused), if not then restart and store the new pid.

Comment: Already i am storing pid in ''pgrep process1 >/Desktop/XYZ/out.txt".

Answer (score 1):

Just start the monitoring code too in their own subprocesses.

```
#!/bin/bash

while :; do
    cd /Desktop/XYZ/
    ./process1
done &

while :; do
    cd /Desktop/XYX/new
    ./process1
done &

read  # halt until it gets input
pkill -P $$  # kill all children
```

I have to add that this is probably not how you want to run your services longterm. You should look into how [systemd service files](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) can do this for you, or any other service manager that your system has.

Comment: i understand it may not for long term service .but as of now using this code , i can restart both process only when both are getting killed .plz give some idea or modify this for when a single process will restart when it get killed without afecting the state of other process

Comment: @bkb My code here does exactly that. Running the two processes independently, monitored in the background. Otherwise I don't understand your question.